# What are the prerequisites for studying modern algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, education

I have studied differential geometry , thought of starting to study algebraic geometry , but it seems completely different from differential geometry . It uses lots of abstract algebraic tools . I wonder how much abstract algebra do I need to learn in order to learn algebraic geometry . Possibly , some reference of algebraic  geometry books will much helpful . 
Another thing I see a lot in lecture notes on introductory algebraic geometry is the usage of angle brackets , i suppose they something completely different . What do they mean , anyway ?

Comment: Citation from the duplicate: No way, you *definitely* need a solid course in Abstract Algebra.

Comment: Isn't just covering the ring theoretic part of abstract algebra enough for the starting ?

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong question. If someone wants to learn English and would ask you "Isn't just covering the verbs enough for the beginning?", what would you answer? My answer would be "Yes, but see, this is not the right question...".

Comment: If you have notions of complex analysis, Riemann surfaces, manifolds, number fields, finite fields, p-adic fields, Galois groups, abstract algebra, then try and see. You'll probably need to go back to Riemann surfaces to make the sheaf and cohomology stuffs clear.